# Folder name of where file is getting logged

Tags: c#, log4net

Here is  how log4net is been setup

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="..\AppLogs\%property{LogName}.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    ............  
</log4net>
```

I know I can get the file name of log file using something like below.

```
var fileAppender = log4net.LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders().First(appender => appender is RollingFileAppender);
```

However , I want to get the folder name where the log file will be created. Is there anyway of getting this?

Comment: Have you tried declaring the file as an instance of System.IO.FileInfo: `FileInfo temppath = new FileInfo("path to file or string variable that represents the path to the file")` then use the Directory member: `var ParentDirectory = temppath.Directory` that should give you the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fileAppender = _logger.Logger.Repository.GetAppenders().OfType<RollingFileAppender>().FirstOrDefault();
```

assuming that you are declaring your instance of the _logger like this

```
private static readonly ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(YourClass));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`File`](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.FileAppender.File.html) property contains the full path to the log file. Once you have that, use `Path.GetDirectoryName` to get the folder.

This MSTest unit test shows that:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Setup()
{
    log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogName"] = "testlogger";

    var fileInfo = new FileInfo("log4net.config.xml");

    if (fileInfo.Exists == false)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't locate the log4net config file");
    }

    LogManager.ResetConfiguration();
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(fileInfo);
}

[TestMethod]
[DeploymentItem(@"log4net.config.xml")]
public void log4net_RollingFileAppender_Is_Configured_Correctly()
{
   var appender = log4net.LogManager.GetRepository()
                                    .GetAppenders()
                                    .OfType<RollingFileAppender>()
                                    .First();

    Console.WriteLine(appender.File);
    Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName(appender.File));
}
```

And in the config:

```
  <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="..\AppLogs\%property{LogName}.txt" />
```

Test result:

[image]